Broke adb on Raspian 11 while attempting to upgrade to newer version
I am attempting connect to my Android TV (an Nvidia Shield TV Pro) using adb from a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian 11. I had initially installed adb using:
 sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot

This installed an older version (v28.X.X) that is incompatible with the Shield. I confirmed that adb was installed and working by running:
adb --version

I then attempted to upgrade adb to a newer version using the files found here. I used wget to download the android-sdk-tools-arm.zip, unzipped it on the pi and copied the adb and fastboot files to /usr/bin/. I realize now this was a mistake as now when I run adb --version I get:
/usr/bin/adb: No such file or directory

Clearly I've messed something up. If I try to remove and reinstall adb with apt-get as I did initially I get:
adb is already the newest version (1:10.0.0+r36-7).
fastboot is already the newest version (1:10.0.0+r36-7).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

And still I get the error when trying to check the adb version.
If anyone could help me out here I would appreciate it! My goal is to install the v35.0.2. of adb and fastboot found here.

zip files usually don't contain the Unix file attributes rwx therefore you have to manually use chmod to make all binaries executable.

@Robert—thanks for responding! That makes sense. I just tried removing the adb and fastboot files in /usr/bin/ and started over. I unizped and copied the two files to /usr/bin using sudo cp ~/android_tools/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/ and sudo cp ~/android_tools/platform-tools/fastboot /usr/bin/. Then changed permissions using sudo chmod +rwx /usr/bin/adb and sudo chmod +rwx /usr/bin/fastboot. But when I run adb --version I still get /usr/bin/adb: No such file or directory. Any other suggestions?
